# C# Take HiddenField Value instead of column name in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

Please tell me if there is any way out to retrieve data from a data table dynamically assigning column name to Hidden Field ? following code may clarify things..

```
HiddenField.Value="MobileNo";

sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Registration_Table where RegistrationNo = '100'", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

is it possible to give

```
Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["HiddenField.Value"].ToString();
```

instead of

```
Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["MobileNo"].ToString();
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you got a `Label` control named as `labelHidden` on your form. You have set `visible` property of that control to `false`. You can assign `Text` of that field to "MobileNo".

You can get data value by

```
Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0][labelHidden.Text].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `Value` of hidden field. Just remove quotes.

```
Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0][HiddenField.Value].ToString();
```